# Is this the best performance using mysql count on multiple joins

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization

I have a DB with the following tables:

- employee
- company
- lt_employee_title

Employees can have multiple titles and companies can have multiple employees.

I'm trying to search on the `lt_employee_title` table and the `company` table and get `employee_id` from the `employee` table.

The table structures:

```
CREATE TABLE `employee` (
  `employee_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `company_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`employee_id`),
  KEY `employee_id` (`company_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `company` (
  `company_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `URL` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `company_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_created` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_updated` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `address1` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address2` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone2` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fax` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `major_city_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `region_code` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `zip` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country_code` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `archived` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `enabled` enum('yes','no') DEFAULT 'yes',
  PRIMARY KEY (`company_id`),
  KEY `country_code` (`country_code`),
  KEY `employee` (`number_of_employees_id`),
  KEY `phone` (`phone`(3)),
  KEY `state` (`region_code`),
  KEY `archived` (`archived`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `lt_employee_title` (
  `employee_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `unique_field` (`employee_id`,`title_id`),
  KEY `employee_id` (`employee_id`),
  KEY `title_id` (`title_id`),
  KEY `both` (`title_id`,`employee_id`),
  KEY `both2` (`employee_id`,`title_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$;
```

This query is fast:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE
  *

FROM lt_employee_title AS let

JOIN employee AS ee
  ON ee.employee_id = let.employee_id

JOIN company AS com
  ON com.company_id = ee.company_id


WHERE let.title_id = 9
  AND com.region_code IN('AL', 'AK', 'AZ')
  AND com.archived = 0


LIMIT 125;
```

But these are not:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE
  COUNT(*)

FROM lt_employee_title AS let
...
```

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
  *

FROM lt_employee_title AS let
...
```

The difference of adding any type of count moves the time from 0.016 seconds to 4.0 seconds.  We have about 250,000 titles, and 900,000 companiy entries and over 1 million employee records but will be growing.

When I add in `count()` or `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` or `ORDER BY com.number_of_employees_id`, the EXPLAIN is using temp tables and file_sort which is why the speed decrease.  Is there a way to do this sql more efficiently?

EXPLAIN WITH "SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS"

```
1   SIMPLE  company ref PRIMARY,state,created,updated,employee_number,archived  state   33  const   210864  Using where; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  employee    ref PRIMARY,employee_id,created,updated employee_id 5   lead411_main.company.company_id 1   Using where; Using index
1   SIMPLE  lt_employee_title   eq_ref  unique_field,employee_id,title_id,both,both2    unique_field    8   lead411_main.employee.employee_id,const 1   Using index
```

EXPLAIN WITH OUT "SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS"

```
1   SIMPLE  company index   PRIMARY,state,created,updated,employee_number,archived  employee    5       986 Using where  
1   SIMPLE  employee    ref PRIMARY,employee_id,created,updated employee_id 5   lead411_main.company.company_id 1   Using where; Using index  
1   SIMPLE  lt_employee_title   eq_ref  unique_field,employee_id,title_id,both,both2    unique_field    8   lead411_main.employee.employee_id,const 1   Using index
```

Comment: what is the count result?

Comment: 5500 or so... as I add more and more states the time to execute keeps getting longer (which is what i'm worried about mostly)

Comment: so, my guess is that the count does not care about the `limit` clause. Try your sql without that clause and see the time is takes to complete.

Comment: Correct... the limit does nothing.. you can basically ignore it.  When you add a count() or SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS is where the bottleneck is.

Comment: So basically what I'm asking is that can I get a total count of the rows faster than I currently am?

Comment: maybe, extract an explain plan of the query without the limit clause and we'll see :-)